# Convergence of moment-generating function of weighted sums of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

This is a continuation of [my earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55265/convergence-of-variance-and-mean-of-weighted-sums-of-random-variables). Once again, let $c_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{c_n} = \infty, \qquad \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{c_n^2} < \infty.$$
Let $X_n$ be a family of i.i.d random variables with $\mathbb{E}(X_n) = 0$ and $\sigma^2(X_n) = 1$ for each $n$, and define the random variable
$$X = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{c_n X_n}.$$
Is it true that the moment-generating function $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})$ exists and is equal to $\prod^{\infty}_{n=1}{\mathbb{E}(e^{c_n t X_n})}$? This seems to be a bit trickier than proving the corresponding question for the characteristic function.

Comment: Your hypothesis does not ensure that $E(\text{e}^{tX_n})$ exists (meaning, is finite), for any real number $t\ne0$.

Comment: Hence, since the $X_n$ are independent, it does not ensure either that $E(\text{e}^{tX})$ is finite. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Did, it is possible that $\mathbb E[e^{tX_n}]=+\infty$ for $t\neq 0$ (the assumption of finiteness of the second moment is not enough). Therefore, by independence, we may have $\mathbb E[e^{tX}]=+\infty$ for $t\neq 0$.